# "Send" is undefined, lost what I've done? | Discord.jsbo

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

```
exports.exec = async (message, bot) => {
    await message.channel.send("Rebooting...").catch(err => this.client.console.error(err));
    process.exit(1);

};
exports.config = {
  aliases: [ ],
  enabled: true,
};

exports.help = {
  name: 'Restart',
  botPermission: '',
  userTextPermission: '',
  userVoicePermission: '',
  usage: 'Restart',
  example: [  ]
};
```

Is the code I've got attempting to run, throws back this error
[image: Photo]

I've got no clue at all, I've done a lot of other commands and all defines are fine but I'm absolutely struggling with this one? I don't see how it's failing at all..

Comment: Can we see more of your code?

Comment: Re-edited original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.exec = async (client, message, args, level) => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send("Are you sure you want to reboot?\n\nReply with `cancel` to abort the reboot. The reboot will self-abort in 30 seconds");
  return message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
    "errors": ["time"],
    "max": 1,
    time: 30000
  }).then(resp => {
    if (!resp) return;
    resp = resp.array()[0];
    const validAnswers = ["yes", "y", "no", "n", "cancel"];
    if (validAnswers.includes(resp.content)) {
      if (resp.content === "cancel" || resp.content === "no" || resp.content === "n") {
        return message.channel.send("Aborting reboot");
      } else if (resp.content === "yes" || resp.content === "y") {
        client.destroy().then(() => {
          process.exit();
        }).catch(error => console.error(error));
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`Only \`${validAnswers.join("`, `")}\` are valid, please supply one of those.`).catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    message.channel.send("Reboot timed out");
  });
};

/* * * * */
```

When inputting **$restart** you'll have an automated reply back from the bot with 
"`Are you sure you want to reboot? Reply with`cancel`to abort the reboot. The reboot will self-abort in 30 seconds`"

If you type "`cancel`" obviously it'll cancel it, if you wait out the time-out it'll also cancel.

**Replying with**

`Yes` | `Y` | 
will restart the bot

`No` | `N` | will cancel it